# Objective-c how to import file programmatically?

Tags: ios

How can I import file programmatically? For example:

```
@interface RoomModel : NSObject

#ifdef DEBUG

#import "fileA.h"   //error : missing context for method declaration

#else

#import "fileB.h"

#endif

@end
```

I know what that mean: I should declare the import in front of the interface. But if I want to import the `.h` file programmatically? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can do that #ifdef logic above the @interface declaration

Comment: You are not trying to import a file programmatically. You are trying to import one header file presumably into another header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import statements must be on top

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#import "fileA.h" 
#else
#import "fileB.h"
#endif

@interface RoomModel : NSObject
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't `import` at runtime, if that's what you're trying to do. It's a preprocessor command, that is executed before compilation.